# Waiting for an observable subscription to complete

Tags: c#, observablecollection, race-condition, observable

Having a few issues with observable. Currently working on a project that is riddled with them and currently they cause quite a few race conditions.

Is there a way to sort of "lock" the application until said observable has received the information it was trying to gather?

Here is the subscription as seen below:

```
serviceLookup.GetAvailableBalance(this.AppointmentGroup)
                .Take(1)
                .Subscribe(ab =>
                {
                        if (ab.Error != null)
                        {
                            SingletonProvider.EventAggregator.Publish(new Error
                            {
                                Exception = ab.Error,
                                Description = "Failed to validate the voucher."
                            });

                            return;
                        }

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab.Result.First().Message))
                        {
                            SingletonProvider.EventAggregator.Publish(new Error
                            {
                                Exception = new Exception("Voucher Validation Error"),
                                Description = ab.Result.First().Message
                            });

                            return;
                        }

                        ObservableCollection<AvailableBalance> balance = ab.GetResult<ObservableCollection<AvailableBalance>, GetAvailableBalanceCompletedEventArgs>();
                });
```

GetAvailable balance will make a call to a service to return the information needed. I want this call to complete before moving any further. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?